# Clickable 2 div and legend form

Tags: javascript, css

I have 2 legends and 2 div, what I want to do is use javascript to **click on the legend (signin_user) then its content is shown** while *other is hidden.*

when another is **clicked (signin_admin) is shown** while **other is hidden**

this is commonly called as tab style login form

**no jquery**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('legend', 'div').forEach(legend, div => {
      div.addEventListener('onclick', () => {
        // change color to selected legend
        this.style.color = "#c8cace"
        //show select div content
        //make another legend  white
        //hide another div content

      })
    })
  })
</script>
<style>
  /* by default signin user is highlighted */
  
  .user {
    background-color: #c8cace;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <div id="user">
    <legend class="user">signin user</legend>
    <input type="text" name="user">
    <input type="submit" id="submit-user">
  </div>
  <div id="admin">
    <legend class="admin">signin admin</legend>
    <input type="text" name="admin">
    <input type="submit" id="submit-admin">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could toggle the class `hide` using `classList` attributes `add/remove` :

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('legend').forEach(function(item) {
    item.addEventListener('click', click_action);
  });
});

function click_action(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();

  //Hide Other divs content
  document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(function(input) {
    input.classList.add('hide');
  });

  //Show licked one content
  event.target.parentNode.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(function(input) {
    input.classList.remove('hide');
  });
}
```

```css
.user {
  background-color: #c8cace;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="user">
  <legend class="user">signin user</legend>
  <input type="text" name="user">
  <input type="submit" id="submit-user">
</div>

<div id="admin">
  <legend class="admin">signin admin</legend>
  <input type="text" name="admin" class="hide">
  <input type="submit" id="submit-admin" class="hide">
</div>
```